# Why did the "type" field disappear when I tried to add new picklist values to the task object in Fields and Relationships?

Tags: tasks, fields, object

I wanted to try and add a few picklist values to the "type" field in the Task object in Salesforce. After I added them in, I went to test it out but the Type field has now completely disappeared. Can someone help me out with why this happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Take a look at the Field Level Security for the `Type` field - it may be turned off for your profile (I can recall this happened to me, when the field is enabled, it wasn't enabled for all (or any) Profiles). This may be related to how old your org is